# How entropy (thermodynamics) related to time flow?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, arrow-of-time

In *Tenet (2020)*, Laura speaks about inverted bullets:

> Laura: It's inverted. Its **entropy** runs backward. So, to our eyes, its movement is reversed. We think it's a type of inverse radiation triggered by nuclear fission.

How entropy (thermodynamics) related to time flow?

Comment: [use a movie scene to explain a movie scene](https://vimeo.com/13810106) p.s: Don't ask me if this physics is accurate LOL

Comment: Btw I think you made a typo, it should be entropy (In title and in body)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/430073/274807 check this post.

Comment: [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/37364)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, thermodynamic entropy is not function of time, but function of thermodynamic state. 2nd law implies only that when adiabatic system goes from equilibrium state 1 to equilibrium state 2, thermodynamic entropy of state 2 cannot be lower than thermodynamic entropy of state 1.

We can introduce more definition of entropy for non-equilibrium processes that is consistent with the previous one for equilibrium states and then 2nd law implies(with caveats) that such entropy cannot sustainably decrease in time, it can only fluctuate - it can spontaneously decrease by small amount for a small time with small probability.

Measuring time flow by entropy increase is a very inaccurate and pointless thing to do. Mechanical or electronic clocks are much better.